# Show that left uniformly continuous functions on a locally compact group G are continuous

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, continuity

Let G be a locally compact group, $\mathcal{C}_{b}(G)=\{f:G \to \mathbb{C} : f \text{ is continuous and bounded}\}$ and $\mathcal{C}_{b\ell u}(G)=\{f:G \to \mathbb{C} : f \text{ is left uniformly continuous and bounded}\}$ where $f : G \to \mathbb{C}$ is left uniformly continuous if $\forall \mathcal{E} >0$ there is an open set $U\subseteq G$ such that $1_{G}\in U$ and $|f(h^{-1}g)-f(g)| < \mathcal{E}$ for all $h \in U$ and $g \in G$.

Show that $\mathcal{C}_{b\ell u}(G)\subseteq \mathcal{C}_{b}(G)$

To show this, we must show that each function $f \in \mathcal{C}_{b\ell u}(G)$ is continuous. I'm not really sure how to get from the above definition to the definition of continuity. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Well, for instance, when $G$ is $\mathbb{R}$ this is just the fact that a uniformly continuous function is continuous.  Do you know how to prove that?  Can you try and adapt the proof?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I know how to prove this for the reals, it's the more general case for any group G that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Well, what difficulty do you have imitating the proof for $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey For a start, I'm a little confused about the definition of continuity for a function on a group. Where we would want |f(x)-f(y)|<e for |x-y|<d when talking about R, how does this carry over to a group without knowing how to measure distance the group?

Comment: Do you know the topological definition of continuity at a point?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey That the pre-image of any open set is open?

Comment: No, that is the definition of continuity everywhere.  The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ is about continuity at a single point, not everywhere, so that's the definition you'll want to use the general form of.